# Maximum Likelihood using Gradient Descent or Coordinate Descent for Normal Distribution with unknown variance

Tags: probability, statistics, optimization, maximum-likelihood, gradient-descent

## Context

The maximum likelihood estimators for a Normal distribution with unknown mean and unknown variance are
$$
\widehat{\mu} = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n x_i \qquad \text{and} \qquad \widehat{\sigma}^2 = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i - \mu)^2
$$
These can be found (for example) by taking derivatives of the average log-likelihood
$$
\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n \log p(x_i) = -\frac{1}{2}\log(2\pi) - \frac{1}{2n\sigma^2}\sum^n_{i=1} (x^{(i)} - \mu)^2 - \log \sigma
$$

## Question: What if I want to use a gradient-based method?

Yes, I know I can just use the estimators found above. However, I want to find such estimators using a gradient-based method such as coordinate descent or gradient descent. These are the gradients with respect to $\mu$ and with respect to $\sigma$ (which you can set equal to zero to find the estimators above)

$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial}{\partial \mu} \frac{1}{n} \sum^n_{i=1} \log p(x^{(i)}) 
&= \frac{\overline{x}}{\sigma^2} - \frac{\mu}{\sigma^2} \\
\frac{\partial}{\partial \sigma} \frac{1}{n}\sum^n_{i=1} \log p(x^{(i)}) &= \frac{1}{n\sigma^3}\sum^n_{i=1}(x^{(i)} - \mu)^2 - \frac{1}{\sigma}
\end{align}
$$
I tried using them in gradient descent
$$
\begin{align}
\mu_{t+1} &\longleftarrow \mu_t + \gamma \left(\frac{\overline{x}}{\sigma^2_t} - \frac{\mu_t}{\sigma^2_t}\right) \\
\sigma_{t+1} &\longleftarrow \sigma_t + \gamma\left(\frac{1}{n\sigma^3_t}\sum^n_{i=1}(x^{(i)} - \mu_{t+1})^2 - \frac{1}{\sigma_t}\right)
\end{align}
$$
or in coordinate ascent (where I would keep, say $\sigma_t$ fixed and optimize $\mu_t$ for $n_{\text{inner}}$ times and then switch: keep $\mu_t$ fixed and optimize $\sigma_t$ for $n_{\text{inner}}$ times. All this for $n_{\text{outer}}$ times. However it seems to blow up for some reason and not give me the obvious answer. You can run the code [here](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1ZinpkC7oj0VHgKRdSLa4qoe24zSbEz75?usp=sharing).

[image: maximum likelihood fails]

> What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The gradient with respect to $\sigma$ is very large when $\sigma$ is less than than the maximizer, and decreases gradually as $\sigma$ grows when it is larger than the maximizer. (See [this plot](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%3D-1%2Fx%5E2-ln%28x%29).) The behavior you are seeing is likely due to a large step size; gradient descent creeps down to the maximizer, but if it overshoots and ends below  the maximizer, it will use the huge gradient to take a giant step upward, erasing all the work you have done.

You have to be careful with gradient methods when the gradient is unbounded or varies sharply like this.

Comment: Would you have any advice then? Should I use a second order method, or simply make the step size smaller?

Comment: @Euler_Salter Both ideas might be good, although I am not sure if the second order method would suffer from a similar issue.

Comment: I tried changing the step size many times but doesn't seem to be leading to any improvement..

Comment: @Euler_Salter You have a typo; the last term of the gradient is $1/\sigma_t$ without a square.

Comment: Do you mean that it should be $- \frac{1}{\sigma_t^2}$ rather than $-\frac{1}{\sigma_t}$ ?

Comment: @Euler_Salter I meant in the code you had sigma**2 mistakenly, but I think you fixed it.

Comment: Yes, it works now! Couldn't make the coordinate ascent version work for some reason, but gradient descent works fine!